# Synchronise Office 365 Group Members

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id, groups

Question:

- I have a list of internal users who are assigned to an office 365 group A. We now want to make other office 365 groups (B, C, ...) that will inherit/synchronize all users from group A and allow for additional external or internal users to be added/removed (unique per team). What is the best architecture to achieve this result?

What I Tried:

- Within Azure AD you can change an office group **membership type** from **Assigned** to **Dynamic user**. This allows me to set the **department** attributes per user to "group A" for example and then create **Dynamic membership rules** per group which checks for these department attributes to assign users.
- The issue with this is that we have 30+ groups and 100+ users. This becomes a lot of work to assign appropriate attributes to each user and rules for each group.

I would appreciate it if there are any better architecture implementations. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you want to do. If you want a dynamic group to use an existing assigned group membership as a membership rule the syntax is `user.memberof -any (group.objectId -in ['value'])` where the `value` is the group ID of group A.  The tricky part is that to add an individual user to that group you have to make a rule that says `user.userPrincipalName -eq "myloginid@domain"`